# How to grep for a 7 digit hexadecimal string and return only that hexadecimal string?

Tags: grep

I am trying to extract all the leading 7 digit hexadecimal strings in a file, that contains lines such as:

```
3fce110:: ..\Utilities\c\misc.c(431): YESFREED (120 bytes) Misc
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
egrep -o '^[0-9a-f]{7}\b' file.txt
```

- `egrep` is the same as `grep -E`; it uses extended regexp.
- `-o` prints only the matching part of each line.
- `^` anchors the match to the beginning of the line.
- `[0-9a-f]{7}` matches seven hexadecimal characters. If you want to match uppercase letters add `A-F` here or add the `-i` flag.
- `\b` checks for a word boundary; it ensures we don't match hex numbers more than 7 digits long.

Comment: If you want the command to be as self-explanatory as possible, you might want to use the long options instead: `grep --only-matching --extended-regexp '^[0-9a-f]{7}' file.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

If all the lines in the file follow the given format then a couple of methods:

```bsh
$ grep -o '^[^:]*' file
3fce110

$ awk -F: '{print $1}' file
3fce110

$ cut -d: -f1 file
3fce110

$ sed  's/:.*//' file
3fce110
```

Comment: I am the downvoter. nice to have so many short commands. but none of them extracts hex string. all of them grep from beginning to the first `:`. no matter what kind of character is, and how many. If OP wants this, the question would be grep text from beginning till the first `:`. So it didn't answer the question correctly in my opinion.

Comment: @Imagination my answer is clearly qualified with the statement `If all the lines in the file follow the given format` and John Kugelman had already posted the method for matching hex numbers. Problems can be solved in a variety of ways and giving the OP many different approaches is definitely beneficial. Your downvote is short sighted.

Comment: `If all the lines in the file follow the given format` OP didn't mention any format, you could even answer `echo 3fce110` I don't want to argue with you on this. You are good at text processing, we can see from your answers at SO. I learned things from your posts too. But **personally** I don't think this answer is correct to the given question. Sorry.